# Why the application crash the whole visual studio when building the application after changed the user control code?

Tags: c#, winforms

The original user control code in the accpected answer in this link : [How to animate dots in UserControl Paint event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788268/how-to-animate-dots-in-usercontrol-paint-event)

i changed it a bit and added and option to save the changes.
so i added some user settings properties one of them is SaveState :

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool SaveState
        {
            get => saveState;
            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    saveState = value;
                }

                Properties.Settings.Default.SaveState = value;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

and in the constructor :

```
public LoadingLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SaveState = Properties.Settings.Default.SaveState;
        }
```

The problem is when i;m adding another line to update the SaveState the whole application and visual studio crash the visual studio start over again without the control being dragged to form1 designer. the crash happens after i made the changes and when dragging the control to the form1 desginer.

This is what i changed :

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool SaveState
        {
            get => saveState;
            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    saveState = value;
                    SaveState = value;
                }
```

I added the line :

```
SaveState = value;
```

because it's updating the saveState and working fine but visually i don't see the property SaveState changing :

The SaveState is set to true but when i'm changing it to false i will see it false only if i will remove and drag the control over again to the designer.

[image: SaveState]

not sure why it's crashing when trying to updating the SaveState it self.

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: In the Costructor, you set the backing Field, not the Property, so `saveState = Properties.Settings.Default.SaveState;` -- Remove `if (value)`, you need to set the backing Field no matter whether the `value` is `true` or `false`. You *could* check whether the new `value` is different from the stored value, if it's the same you do nothing, when it's useless to do the same thing -- Here: `SaveState = value;`, you're creating a recursive call to the setter, which will crash the whole thing. In the Property setter, you - again - set the backing Field, not the Property

Comment: @Jimi i changed it to the saveState in the constructor and in the SaveState i removed the line SaveState = value; and removed also the if(value) but still when i'm setting in form1 the property SaveState to false or true it will take affect only when i drag the control over again.  the SaveState in form1 is not changing if it's true it will stay true even if i changed it to false until i will drag the control over again.  i want to see the state i changed to also if not dragging the control over again.

Comment: @Jimi i mean that only when i'm dragging the control to form1 designer over again only then it will change the state of the SaveState property of the control.  it's like i need to make instance each time of the control to change the state.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If the Property is setup correctly, of course you will see the value change in the PropertyGrid. If you mean that you have two instances of the same Control and you change the Property value in one, this is not reflected in the other, it's because you have not subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event of `Properties.Settings.Default`, which - when triggered - should set the backing Field. When you do that, switching from one instance to the other in the Form designer, causes the PropertyGrid to read again the Property values, so the Property is updated in all instances

Comment: @Jimi working great.  what if i want to change a bit the SaveState behviour ? now when i need to change the saveState to true first then change other properties to make it save the changes.  but what if i want to make that for example i changed the interval property first then changed the SaveState to true so it will make a save and then if i changed the SaveState back to false when dragging the control over again it will be with the saved changes.

Comment: @Jimi so the SaveState will be like a switch if true save false don't save.  now it's acting like first i need to change it to true and then change properties. but i want that if i changed a property value and then changed the SaveState to true then save too.

Comment: @jimi to keep the SaveState behviour like it is now and also adding the "button" behaviour too.  when changing to true the SaveState make a save of all made changes and changes i will make later when false don't save at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
SaveState = value;
```

you call the setter.

When you do so in the setter's code, this causes infinite recursion - you assign to `SaveState` in the setter, which calls the setter, which assigns to `SaveState`, which calls the setter, which assigns to `SaveState`, which calls the setter, and so forth forever, which is causing the IDE to crash.

The moral of the story: **NEVER** assign to the property inside the setter; **ALWAYS** assign to the backing field instead.